# Beta function problem

Tags: special-functions

Write the following integral in the form of Beta function

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \tan(2x)\, \mathrm{d}x$$

I know that I can use this
$$B(p,q)=2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{2p-1}(x) \cos^{2q-1}(x)\, \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: The integral does not converge.

Comment: $B(1,0)$. Useless.

Comment: $\tan\left(2x\right)\ =\  \cot\left({\pi \over 2} - 2x\right)\ =\ {1 \over \tan\left(\pi/2 - 2x\right)}\,\,\, \sim\ {1 \over 2}\,{1 \over \pi/4 - x}\quad\mbox{when}\quad x\ \sim\ {\pi \over 4}$.

Answer (score 2):

A primitive of $\tan(2x)$ is clearly  $-\frac{1}{2}\ln(\cos(2x))$.

This primitive is undefined for $x=-\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Thus the integral is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Through the formal substitutions $x=\arctan u$ and $u=v^{1/4}$ we get:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\tan(2x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}2u(1-u^4)^{-1}\,du \tag{1}$$
from which:
$$ I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}v^{-3/4}(1-u)^{-1}\,du = \frac{1}{2}\,B\left(\frac{1}{4},0\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\Gamma(0)}{2\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}=\frac{\Gamma(0)}{2}\tag{2}$$
but the $\Gamma$ function has a simple pole at $z=0$, hence the integral is diverging. Anyway, I think that to prove the divergence of the integral through that machinery is definitely an overkill.